# Star rating jquery not working for more than one instance

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used the jQuery used in this https://codepen.io/alisuarez/pen/RWGNLm

The problem here is since class is used in the function all the star ratings work simultaneously. In jQuery when I use ID it works for one particular row of ratings as expected. I am cloning the row into multiple rows dynamically. How can I run the jQuery for each id star-rating1, star-rating2 etc?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```js
var $star_rating = $('#star-rating .fa');

var SetRatingStar = function() {
  return $star_rating.each(function() {
    if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >=
      parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    } else {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
    }
  });
};

$star_rating.on('click', function() {
  $star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
  return SetRatingStar();
});

SetRatingStar();
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="star-rating" id="star-rating">
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="whatever1" class="rating-value" value="2.56">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="star-rating" id="star-rating">
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="whatever2" class="rating-value" value="1.9">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to scope the click event handler to only run on the clicked rating instance rather than on all ratings with the same value. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as expected
  HTML

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12 abc">
  <div class="star-rating">
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="whatever1" class="rating-value" value="2.56">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 abc">
  <div class="star-rating">
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="whatever2" class="rating-value" value="1.9">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
   </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.abc').click(function(){
  var $star_rating = $(this).find('.star-rating .fa');



var SetRatingStar = function() {
 return $star_rating.each(function() {
if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
  return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
 } else {
  return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
}
});
};

$star_rating.on('click', function() {
$star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
return SetRatingStar();
});
});
SetRatingStar();
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question or attempting to add to your original post?

Comment: Answering my question since I got the solution

Comment: Accept it once you are able to so others know that the question is no longer open. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest binding the event listener to the stars parent element and event delegating: `$star_rating.on('click', '.fa', function(){});`

Then only run the star setting functionality on the instance of a rating that is changed.

```
// Set the variable to the star container.
var $star_rating = $('.star-rating');

// This runs the setStars function below for each and every rating instance.
var SetRatingStar = function() {  
  $star_rating.each(setStars);
};


function setStars() {
  // We use $(this) to only run the code for the calling instance of 
  // $('.star-rating') rather than all

  // Use a var to store the current rating value.
  var ratingVal = parseInt( $(this).find('input.rating-value').val());
  // Clear all filled classes and add open class to all stars.
  $(this).children().removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
  // While the i var is less than the total rating value, use eq(i) to add 
  // the filled class to the star
  for(var i = 0; i < ratingVal; i ++)
   $(this).children().eq(i).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');  
}

$star_rating.on('click', '.fa', function() {  
        $(this).siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).index() + 1);
        // Calls setStars function with $(this) value set to the parent container.
        setStars.call($(this).parent());
    });


$(document).ready(function() {
  SetRatingStar();
});
```

Working example on codepen:
[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZOZMK?editors=0011)